# why i get notice:undefined constant PHPWEATHER_BASE_DIR

Tags: php

I want to make use of project PHPWeather 2.2.2 but it gives me many errors

In line 1 I got an error message

```
Use of undefined constant PHPWEATHER_BASE_DIR - assumed 'PHPWEATHER_BASE_DIR' in C:\wamp\www\phpweather-2.2.2\data_retrieval.php on line 1
```

Here is a code

```
require_once(PHPWEATHER_BASE_DIR . '/db_layer.php');

class data_retrieval extends db_layer {
  var $metar;
  var $metar_time;
  var $metar_arch;
  var $taf;
  var $icao_data;
  var $time_from;
  var $time_to;

  function data_retrieval($input = array()) {

    /* We start by calling the parent constructor. */
    $this->db_layer($input);

    /* Then we set the station. */
    $this->set_icao($this->properties['icao']);

    $this->metar = false;
    $this->metar_time = false;
    $this->metar_arch = false;
    $this->time_from = false;
    $this->time_to = false;

  }
}
```

Comment: Have you defined `PHPWEATHER_BASE_DIR` anywhere?

Comment: Is PHP Weather included before you use `PHPWEATHER_BASE_DIR`?

Comment: actually this a php weather project which i want to use not made by me
It is an old project that's why it has many errors
no, it is not use anywhere in project as i check it

Comment: It is use in this way define('PHPWEATHER_BASE_DIR', dirname(__FILE__));

Answer (score 0):

try adding this

```
define('PHPWEATHER_BASE_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/..');
```

before

```
require_once(PHPWEATHER_BASE_DIR . '/db_layer.php');
```

Please note that this is just an estimation you need to specify the proper location in place of `'/..'` where your `db_layer.php` exists from the root of your project